# How to deploy a windows image on Heroku?

Tags: asp.net, docker, heroku

I'm trying to `deploy` a `Windows` `container` on [`Heroku`](http://heroku.com/) but i'm getting the following error:

> ```
> image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
> ```

I have this information on `Heroku's` website:

> **Develop with Docker, deploy to Heroku**
>
> Use Docker for local development on Windows, Linux, or Mac. When you're ready, just push your code and Dockerfile to build and deploy your Docker images to Heroku.

Which leads me to think that it is possible to perform `deploy` using a `Windows` image.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

And this is my `heroku.yml`:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: swagger-aspnet-docker/Dockerfile
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Comment: I don't see an official reference so I'm not going to give an answer, but that quote says nothing about Windows (or macOS) _images_. It's talking about your _host machine_. Given how Windows is licensed I'm not surprised that this is restricted. And AFAIK it's still not possible to run Windows containers on non-Windows hosts. I'm pretty sure Heroku doesn't use Windows hosts.

Comment: @Chris thank you for your comment. It's possible to use another image for asp.net that's not a `Windows` image?

Comment: I'm not sure. It probably depends on whether you can get away with .NET Core or if you need the full framework. There are [Linux tags for the official ASP.NET Core runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/) images, and it looks like the defaults use Linux containers (based on Debian Stretch).